# Vertically align a nested div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while. I have tried many methods including table-cell, top:50%, giving the container a fixed height and trying to center div 1 within it... Nothing is working without messing up the size of the 2 inner divs.

I don't want it to be relative to the viewport width because the background of the page is going to be a fixed image and I'd like the logo to be in a fixed position over the image, but the solutions I've tried (top 50% and such) cause the logo to be centered no matter the size of the viewport. I'm guessing here I'm going to need to set a fixed height on the body but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

```
<body>
<div id="logowrap">
    <div id="outerlogo">
        <div id="innerlogo">LOGOHERE</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#logowrap{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width:300px;
}

#outerlogo{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    border: 2px solid #656565;
    position: absolute;
    display: table; 
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#innerlogo{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border: 2px solid #656565;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: Garamond, Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

Comment: Jsfiddle this please...

Comment: Everything seems fine, I've checked your code and everything is aligned perfectly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56hbevke/ is this not what you are looking for? Don't understand the issue you are having. Can you please clarify.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to align an element to a background image...right? If we don't have the image how can we help? A demo **with the image** is probably going to be required.

Comment: Sorry I can't believe I didn't actually state what I was trying to achieve. I'm just trying to center the div with the text logo in it to the center of the screen. It's centered horizontally but not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#logowrap {
    width:300px;
    height:130px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-65px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
#outerlogo {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    border: 2px solid #656565;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#innerlogo {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border: 2px solid #656565;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: Garamond, Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="logowrap">
        <div id="outerlogo">
            <div id="innerlogo">LOGOHERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Try this. The inner divs dimensions were specified with **px**, so making the **#logowrap** dimension fixed doesn't broke anything. If it's what you were looking for, +1 and accept. If not, comment.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I am trying to center the logo vertically. It's already centered horizontally but I can't get it to the middle of the page without the formatting becoming extremely strange. Thanks for your input

Comment: With the code provided, it is aligned vertically(see the snippet in full page mode) too, not just horizontally.